# "Pod install" gets rid of all run build phases scripts

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have Cocoapods library and an example project where I can run the library from. In my library I have few scripts such as: a swiftlint script which runs perfectly fine. However, every time I do "pod install" from my example project, my scripts in the build phase get removed.

I am unsure what causes this behaviour. I have tried using legacy build system but that didn't do anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are running the Build Phase associated with the Pods project, as seen here:

[image]

Every time you run `pod install` or `pod update`, Cocoapods will rebuild the Pods project, resulting in any changes you make to it going poof.

Instead, you need to get a little creative and place that command in your Example project. I make `swiftlint` work inside a pod by placing the script inside the Build Phase for my Example project and then call it like this:

```
if which "${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint" >/dev/null; then
    cd ../YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER
    swiftlint
else
echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

You may have to modify the path to match yours, but the important part is that it will run this script inside your Example project. Assuming your pod uses the default paths, then `cd ../YOUR_PROJECT_NAME` should work. If you use a different path, then adjust as necessary.

You can also echo out the path if that helps you find it when running.